# DevExpress Problem with self reference association

Tags: .net, devexpress

I am using the DevExpress [eXpressApp Framework](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Application_Framework/) to develop an LOB app for an insurance agency.  My problem is in the area of the *domain objects* (business objects) and their *associations*, or relations.

I have a MyPerson object, primarily a PolicyHolder instance, and I need to associate a Spouse and Children of the same class to the PolicyHolder.  When I tried the following code in the MyPersonn class, ran the code and tried to add a spouse, I got the error:

"There is a malformed association 'Person-Spouse'. Cannot find the associated member for 'PolicyMIS.Module.MyPerson.Spouse' in the class 'PolicyMIS.Module.MyPerson'"

```
    private MyPerson _spouse;
    [Association("Person-Spouse", typeof(MyPerson))]
    public MyPerson Spouse
    {
        get
        {
            return _spouse;
        }

        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("Spouse", ref _spouse, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Giving the *exact* error would be clearer, and it isn't obvious to me what this has to do with DevExpress....

Comment: I've added the error, but if the title doesn't suggest this is something to do with DevExpress I don't know what will.

Comment: Nothing explains how or where you're using DevExpress...

Comment: @C.Ross, noted and amended.  I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Despite this question being down-voted, it has given me one very useful answer and engaged me in an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the results retuned by our search engine for your problem:

[self-reference association](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=self-reference+association&p=T4|P2|0&d=959)

Does this help?

If not, we need more information about your task.

Comment: Thanks @DevExpressTeam, that sorts my problem out for my Children property, but I'm still a bit baffled for Spouse, because your in example a Manager and Subordinates are distinct properties, whereas Spouse is not, and I can't have two Spouse properties for both ends of the association.